How to use mage.exe for (re)signing manifests with Azure Trusted Code Signing
We have a setup in which we build clickonce deployments on our build server and then redeploy them later on several customer servers. The problem there is that you have to resign the manifest file after changing the deployment url (because, obviously, that's different for every site). We have built a tool to help resigning the manifest after setting the new deployment url. Under the hood, it uses mage.exe.
Now we have recently set up an "Azure Trusted Code Signing" account in order to be able to sign our code files with a trusted certificate and a cloud service is a perfect way to do that...
However: how do you marry the two? Mage.exe doesn't seem to have a built-in mechanism to use the Azure code signing service, only an option in which you provide the certificate file. But the whole point of this cloud service is that you don't have the certificate file because it's in a safe place there...
Any tips?
I have tried looking into the mage.exe options, but there's nothing that can be used. I also tried stackoverflow and found a suggestion to skip clickonce alltogether, but I can't simply change our deployment method.

I'm having the same issues now. I've found some information about it here: https://github.com/dotnet/sign#clickonce, but in my case I'm deploying a VSTO add-in using Inno Installer, so the method does not apply directly.

Thanks, but the link seems to refer toe Azure Key Vault, which is something different than the newer Trusted Code Signing service that I'm referring to.
